# Add table to template PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

I have a template .docx file in which I want to place a table. I can already read-in the template file and search-and-replace simple strings in the template.

But now I want to put a table in the template.

This is my code:

```php
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($template);
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$templateProcessor->setValue('customer_name', $name); 
$templateProcessor->setValue('customer_address', $address); 
$templateProcessor->setValue('customer_city', $city); 
$templateProcessor->setValue('customer_name', $name); 
$templateProcessor->setValue('invoice_date', $date); 

$table_section = $phpWord->addSection();
$rows = 10;
$cols = 5;
$table_section->addText('Basic table', "rofl");

$table = $table_section->addTable();
for ($r = 1; $r <= $rows; $r++) {
    $table->addRow();
    for ($c = 1; $c <= $cols; $c++) {
        $table->addCell(1750)->addText("Row {$r}, Cell {$c}");
    }
}

$objWriter = new PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\Word2007($phpWord);
$tableStr = $objWriter->getWriterPart('Document')->getTableAsText($table);

$templateProcessor->setValue('product_table', $tableStr); 


$templateProcessor->saveAs($new_file_path);
```

I have added this:

```php
/* CUSTOM FUNCTION */
function getTableAsText($element) {
    $xmlWriter = $this->getXmlWriter();
    $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\Word2007\Element\Table($xmlWriter, $element);
    $writer->write();
    return $xmlWriter->getData();
}
```

to `PhpWord/Writer/Word2007/Part/Document.php`.

As output I just get all the rows as a paragraph, not at all as a table...

Answer (score 0):

```
This is just a siple table customized  with width and color. you also have to add and on top of you page.
 
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter;
$fancyTableStyleName = 'Fancy Table';
$fancyTableStyle = array('borderSize' => 1, 'borderColor' => '006699', 'cellMargin' => 0, 'alignment' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\JcTable::CENTER, 'cellSpacing' => 0);
$fancyTableFirstRowStyle = array('borderBottomSize' => 1, 'borderBottomColor' => '0000FF', 'bgColor' => '66BBFF');
$fancyTableCellStyle = array('valign' => 'center');
$fancyTableCellBtlrStyle = array('valign' => 'center', 'textDirection' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Cell::TEXT_DIR_BTLR);
$fancyTableFontStyle = array('bold' => true);
$phpWord->addTableStyle($fancyTableStyleName, $fancyTableStyle, $fancyTableFirstRowStyle);
$table = $section->addTable($fancyTableStyleName);
$table->addRow(900);
$table->addCell(2000, $fancyTableCellStyle)->addText('Row 1', $fancyTableFontStyle);
$table->addCell(2000, $fancyTableCellStyle)->addText('Row 2', $fancyTableFontStyle);


    $table->addRow();
    $table->addCell(2000)->addText("Cell 1");
    $table->addCell(2000)->addText("Cell 2");
```